# get Object from json file by Gson lib, have java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException error

Tags: java, json, casting, gson

my code used Gson lib for Convert .json file to a Java Model with this code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("C:\\developers.json"));
        List<Developer> devList = new Gson().fromJson(br, Collections.<Developer>emptyList().getClass());
        for (Developer d : devList) {
            System.out.println(d.getAge());
        }
    }
```

error that occurred , refer to second argument of `fromJson`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

this error is for casting. after searching i don't find better than this code. 
I don't know what is wrong?
Thanks for any Guidance to Solve it.

**edit:**
developers.json ->

```
[
  {
    "name": "mkyong",
    "age": 120,
    "salary": 1555002
  },
  {
    "name": "amir",
    "age": 20,
    "salary": 3000000
  }
]
```

and Developer.java ->

```
public class Developer {

    private String name;
    private BigDecimal salary;
    private Integer age;

...
getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is being thrown because Gson is creating an instance of the type of List returned by `emptyList()`, and then attempting to add elements to it. The type of list returned by this method is [immutable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList()), which leads to the `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Instead of using `emptyList().getClass()`, you should use a `TypeToken` for deserializing generic types, as described in the [Gson user guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types).

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Developer>>() {}.getType();
List<Developer> devList = new Gson().fromJson(br, listType);
```

Comment: OK!! This Worked fine. Thank you.